# attempt to compare a number with nil

Tags: lua

I'm having issues with the below error:

> esx_glovebox_sv.lua:138: attempt to compare number with nil.

Line 138 is third in RAW data below

```
RegisterServerEvent("esx_glovebox:getItem")
AddEventHandler(
  "esx_glovebox:getItem",
  function(plate, type, item, count, max, owned)
    local _source = source
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source)

    if type == "item_standard" then
      local targetItem = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(item)
      if targetItem.limit == -1 or ((targetItem.count + count) <= targetItem.limit) then
        TriggerEvent(
          "esx_glovebox:getSharedDataStore",
          plate,
          function(store)
            local coffres = (store.get("coffres") or {})
            for i = 1, #coffres, 1 do
              if coffres[i].name == item then
                if (coffres[i].count >= count and count > 0) then
                  xPlayer.addInventoryItem(item, count)
                  if (coffres[i].count - count) == 0 then
                    table.remove(coffres, i)
                  else
                    coffres[i].count = coffres[i].count - count
                  end

                  break
                else
                  TriggerClientEvent(
                    "pNotify:SendNotification",
                    _source,
                    {
                      text = _U("invalid_quantity"),
                      type = "error",
                      queue = "glovebox",
                      timeout = 3000,
                      layout = "bottomCenter"
                    }
                  )
                end
```

Comment: you said "138 is third in RAW data below", the third what? line? Also a suggestion, try temporarily adding a print call to print the variables used in your comparison right before you use them, it can really help you when trying to debug an issue like this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your post correctly "line 138" points to the third line in your posted code snippet, which would be:

```
if targetItem.limit == -1 or ((targetItem.count + count) <= targetItem.limit) then
```

The error means, that one of the values you are working with is `nil` and therefore can't be compared to a number. In your case this can only be `targetItem.limit`.

If each `targetItem` should have a `limit` and `count` value, the issue is somewhere else in your code.

Instead of throwing an error you can simply check for the existance of the value by adding additional checks:

```lua
if type == "item_standard" then
  local targetItem = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(item)

  -- Make sure that targetItem and targetItem.limit aren't nil.
  if targetItem and targetItem.limit then
    if targetItem.limit == -1 or ((targetItem.count + count) <= targetItem.limit) then
```

Short explanation: In Lua both `nil` and the boolean value `false` represent a `false` value inside of a logical expression. *Any* other value will be treated as `true`. In this case you'll skip the nested if-statement if either `targetItem` or `targetItem.limit` are `nil`.

Comment: Since `targetItem.count` and `count` are first added together, the only variable that gets directly compared with a number is `targetItem.limit`, so it can only be that one that's causing the error ;)